# joomla https: Error 310, too many redirects

Tags: apache-http-server, proxy, php, ssl, joomla

I have joomla 3.5.1 running under apache 2.4 behind an nginx reverse proxy. It works fine without SSL. My nginx does SSL fine, and then proxies the requests (in plain HTTP) to apache.
I followed the usual guides to move joomla to the https domain, edited live_site in configuration.php, experimented with different values of force_ssl. However, I keep getting "too many redirects" in my browser.
What's the correct way to move a joomla installation to https in a setup that involves nginx -> apache -> php-fpm?

Answer (score 0):

Found this old question after a web search trying to navigate SSL issues with Nginx on Joomla.

Firstly, it looks like this issue will go away with v3.7.
In the meantime, you can read more on solutions on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41268975/mixed-ssl-content-preventing-joomla-installation-operation-with-nginx/41299376#41299376)